# T1 font encoding, newtxtext, and microtype result in “Package microtype Info: Character `029' is missing”

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, small-caps, microtype, newtx

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\textsc{}% doesn't matter what text we enter here
\end{document}
```

to pdflatex prints

```
Package microtype Info: Character `029' is missing
(microtype)             in font `T1/ntxtlf/m/sc/10'.
(microtype)             Ignoring protrusion settings for this character.
```

to the log (sometimes we do search for `missing` in the log to check whether there are any problems). If we drop `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, we get a complaint about 013 instead of 029.

Which character (029 and 013 are just numbers and not characters) is missing where? What does the aforementioned message in the log tell us, especially given the fact that no text is output via `\textsc`? (You can even suppress the page number with `\pagestyle{empty}` to get really no text on the page at all.) Is this message something to worry about? If so, who should worry, and, (most importantly ) who is the culprit?

EDIT (based on the comments and answers of [Ulrike Fischer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682319/t1-font-encoding-newtxtext-and-microtype-result-in-package-microtype-info-ch#comment1692961_682319), [rallg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682319/t1-font-encoding-newtxtext-and-microtype-result-in-package-microtype-info-ch#comment1693007_682319), and [Stephen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686135)): The message in the log is useless for the very input above and even annoying because it takes up space and distracts the author without need. However, if the input contains `\textsc{ﬂ}`, we'd better be informed or even warned that the output does not contain a real ligature (because the output has the small capitals ꜰʟ instead). We still need the (now present) additional warning “Missing character: There is no ^^] in font ntx-Regular-tlf-sc-t1!” message in the log if the input contains `\textsc{\char29}`, and we wish that the part “^^]” be a bit less enigmatic.

Comment: char29 is the fl ligature, and it is missing in the small caps font, as long as you don't try to access it directly with \char29, there is nothing to worry.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know, thanks! Microtype should issue their “missing” message only on need (e.g., when `\textsc{\char29}` or `\textsc{ﬂ}` is encountered).

Comment: Among the package options for `microtype`, there is one that reduces the number of messages. Also, the `silence` package can reduce unnecessary messages. But as mentioned, it is easiest to just ignore that Info.

Answer (score 1):

`char29` is the `fl` ligature. This is missing in the small caps font (`\textsc{...}`). As long as neither `\char29` not `fl` is used in small caps, there is nothing to worry about and the information from microtype can be ignored. Usually `fl` input is `FL` output in small caps (!), i.e. `fl` *is* not used in small caps output.

The [microtype](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package provides the option `verbose` with values `true`, `false`, `errors`, and `silent` to adjust the amount of shown messages, but "Package microtype Info: Character ... is missing" is not affected by the setting of this option. The [silence](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) package can be used to filter out unwanted warning and error messages, but the message here is neither a warning nor an error but an info, and thus it is not filtered out.

If you have a very strong need to never to see any info about a missing `fl` in `\textsc`, then you can put

```
\makeatletter
\let\originalMT@info@missing@char\MT@info@missing@char

\def\MT@info@missing@char{%
  \def\privateMTc{029}%
  \edef\privateMTv{\the\MT@toks}%
  \ifx\privateMTc\privateMTv%
    \def\privateMTc{sc}%
    \ifx\privateMTc\f@shape%
    \else%
      \originalMT@info@missing@char%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \originalMT@info@missing@char%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble after loading `microtype`.

[With help from the comments by Ulrike Fischer, AlMa0, and rallg - thanks!]

Comment: Thanks! There are caveats if we introduce your edit: (1) If the input contains `\textsc{ﬂ}` (without us actively knowing this), then the fact that the output is NOT a ligature but ꜰʟ goes unnoticed in the log. (2) If the input contains `\textsc{\char29}` (without us actively knowing this), then the *only* log message telling us that something goes wrong is `Missing character: There is no ^^] in font ntx-Regular-tlf-sc-t1!`, which is too enigmatic concerning the character.

Comment: @AlMa0 I thought text-small-caps would mean small caps, i. e. a smaller F and a smaller L. Is there any font which has a ligature for "FL"? Ligatures for "fl" do certainly exist.